# Solr - Removing text inside pattern

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working with Solr. And indexed one field as Windows!!1!!, where !!1!! is a display order used at the time of display when data is being displayed on front-end. The field type is string.

Moreover, this field is an indexed field, and we need to perform search on the same. Can you advise, how we can remove !!1!! using some filter factory from the field that is used to perform search?

I am planning to create a copy field for this field and destination field will be text field as we need to apply analyzers and tokenizers. Is there a way to remove !!1!! using some kind of pattern?

Here are some of the sample texts I am indexing:

Windows!!1!!

Android Phone!!5!!

12 terabytes!!15!!

12 gb!!0!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have . Have a look at below given solr classes for pattern based replacement .

```
 <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=""/>
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=";\s*" />
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
```

Experiment your data with any one of the following in your custom analyzer, it will work for sure. Let me know if that helps :) Use following analyzer for your field , i tried and it worked !!

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Actually i figured out i was a bit wrong in giving my answer . You don't need any pattern replace factory at all !! `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory` does it all for you . It removes ! as a default behaviour . Have a look at this snapshot from solr documentation .[image]

**EDIT III** : Use following analyzer , its working !!

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([!\dx!])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Also attaching a snapshot of my solr analysis screen , using above analyzer . You can see effect at the "PRF" stage in the image . "1" digit between exclamation marks is also removed , thanks to above regex. You can tailor your solution accordingly .
[image]

Let me know if that helps :) .

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just reviewed them, I think solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory would be better choice. What do you recommend?

Comment: Ok, so I just need to figure out regex pattern! Any idea on that one!

Comment: Hey i just validated that you dont need any pattern replace factory especially to remove ! sign . See my updated answer .

Comment: I need to remove !! as well as data between !!

Comment: are you sure that there will always be a number between those exclamation marks ??

Comment: i guess i found the solution , and it is working . I am updating my answer .

Comment: Got it working with following: 

<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="!!.*?!!" replacement=""/>

thank you for your help.

Comment: great !!!  ya i was about to comment that still my solution had one flaw